# Accept parameters only from POST request in python

Tags: python, post, cgi

Is there a way to accept parameters only from POST request?
If I use cgi.FieldStorage() from cgi module, it accepts parameters from both GET and POST request.

Comment: May I suggest that you avoid CGI in the first place?

Comment: Do you mean python cgi module? If yes, no problem to avoid it. I just want a way to do what I asked.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but the way to do it depends on what web framework you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, most things in the `cgi` module merge `os.environ['QUERY_STRING']` and `sys.stdin` (in the format suggested by `os.environ['CONTENT_TYPE']`).  So the simple solution would be to modify `os.environ`, or rather, provide an alternative, with no query string.

```
# make a COPY of the environment
environ = dict(os.environ)
# remove the query string from it
del environ['QUERY_STRING']
# parse the environment
form = cgi.FieldStorage(environ=environ)
# form contains no arguments from the query string!
```

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggests avoiding the `cgi` module altogether;  modern python web apps should usually adhere to the [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Frameworks) interface.  That might instead look like:

```
import webob
def application(environ, start_response):
    req = webob.Request(environ)
    if req.method == 'POST':
        # do something with req.POST

# still a CGI application:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import wsgiref.handlers
    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

Comment: Perfect! They are both good ways, but I prefer don't use external modules in this case, so I'll use the first way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's unfortunate.  An amazing amount of work is totally boilerplate when dealing with web-apps.  `webob` is about the thinnest veneer of a no-framework framework around for wsgi (it's even less magical than `cgi` but is generally more useful).  You really should build your app on top of a solid framework and focus on the actual *problem you're trying to solve*

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, I think you can do the following:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
if isinstance(form["key"], cgi.FieldStorage):
     pass #handle field
```

This code is untested.

Comment: This seems a way to reject "key" parameter and I don't want this. I want to accept a parameter only from POST request and not GET.

Comment: This is supposed to to only handle POST requests. URL parameters in GET requests use `cgi.MiniFieldStorage`. It might not be fail safe (for example, for when you come across a POST request with URL parameters), but it's a quick fix.

Comment: Mmm...I tried (with both POST and GET request), but it doesn't work, I don't get anything.